# What is the best method for saving a lot of objects states?

Tags: c#, serialization, unity-game-engine, save

I am currently integrating serialization into a Unity3D game, where I need to store up to thousands of game object positions to file as the user will be placing them down themselves. This will be done on mobile and saving an entire scene during play will hang the processor way too long.

What is the best method for saving the game state?

- Save each objects position when it is changed
- Save all objects when the application is quit or paused

How should I save the objects?

- Each as an individual file for faster saving (and include a manager
  class that maintains reference to the serialized files names)
- An entire hierarchy with all objects at a time for simplicities sake
  which will hang the processor when saving

Also should I keep a memory stream open the entire game, or only open it when an object is saved?

Comment: this question is off topic unfortunately, but my recommendation is to use protobuf-net. It is extremely fast, flexible and should be able to handle a hierarchy of thousands of objects. You should make a large test object and see how long serizlisation/deserialisation takes. Furthermore I recommend only to save when quit/pause, disk access is several orders slower than memory

Comment: protobuf-net ftw. An excellent library. Leaves standard .NET serialization in the dust.